# Swift "Extraneous argument label in 'contentsOf' in call" when trying to use insert on a String

Tags: swift

I'm working in a swift playground while going through the Swift documentation on Apple's website. Specifically [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID285) First I have to say it is pretty challenging because several of the methods they describe are not current and have different syntax than in the documentation. I've found the answers to all my questions up to now in previous questions that have been asked on here. This one I can't seem to find exactly. Anyways I have resorted to directly copy pasting the code from the documentation and it still isn't working. Here it is:

```
import UIKit
var welcome = "hello"
welcome.insert(contentsOf: " there", at: welcome.index(before: welcome.endIndex))
```

And I am told that contentsOf is extraneous. Swift even suggested this exact method as I typed it in, argument labels and all. Any insight is much appreciated.

Edit: Thanks folks, answered.

Comment: You're reading the documentation for Swift 4, which is still in beta.  You'll want to either use the Xcode 9 beta, wait for the official release this fall, or find some older documentation.

Comment: FWIW, this is happening in an Xcode 8 playground

Comment: Ah okay thanks both of you. I didn't realize swift 4 is still in beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error's confused because of the overloaded nature of the function. The real problem is you're passing it a String instead of a Collection.

try this:

```
welcome.insert(contentsOf: " there".characters, at: welcome.index(before: welcome.endIndex))
```

Comment: Thanks yea that's it.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

This will work if you're trying to insert a string into another string.

```
welcome.insert(contentsOf: String(" there"), at: welcome.index(welcome.startIndex, offsetBy: 5))
```